# Received an unsolicited two-factor security code on my phone: bad?

Tags: passwords, multi-factor

As above, I received a code (twice!) on my phone for a security code for PayPal with no further text than the number. Should I be worried someone has successfully obtained my password and accidentally alerted me to their success, or is it more likely someone mistyped their number is mine? Are there other signs I would see if my password had been stolen somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is probably a bad sign.

First of all, though: This might simply be a phishing mail that hopes you click some link in the mail that says "report a problem with this email to Paypal", but takes you to a different website than the real paypal site and lets you enter your credentials there. So, the worst thing you can do is click on any link from this mail. You could check for the links' actual target – if they're not on servers that are unambiguously paypal.com, then you can be pretty certain this is nothing but an attempt to phish.

Go to https://paypal.com (maybe using another machine than the one you're normally using to enter your Paypal credentials, since you've got reason to assume it has been compromised), check the certificate of that website your getting looks correct, and find a contact phone number to call. Change your Paypal password from a machine you can reasonably well assume is free of malware that might try to steal your credentials.

Comment: To clarify: it was a text message I received on my phone with a code, not an email. And I got two different texts with different codes. Something I'd expect if I forgot a password or attempting to log in from a new computer. Does that change things?

Comment: yeah, it reduces the phish likelihood. change your password, contact paypal.

Comment: When I called, they said there had been no login attempts of any kind (successful or failed), aside from when I changed my password.  The person told me that the SMS I received was related to their help system - the 6 digit code is for verifying identity of callers.  Sounds like I got lucky... this time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means someone has attempted to go into one of your accounts and has instead triggered an SMS alert to your phone. Usually web forms default to resetting the password by email or such if a phone is not added on the account.

Comment: That's if it's genuine and not spoofed for phishing purposes.